# How to use php to avoid duplication on database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to make a unique value column in my table,and use php to check if the value is already Inserted into the table or not. For example, one username cannot be used twice.
I tried to use SELECT to get value from database,but it does not work.
When I tried to echo the value from table like that:

```
echo $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT Username
FROM UserDetail;");
```

It says:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem should not be solved in PHP because it's a database design issue.  Instead, you want to alter your `UserDetail` table so that the DB will reject any query that tries to insert a duplicate.  This is the query you run:

```
$sql = 'ALTER TABLE UserDetail ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`Username`)';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result) echo 'Success!';
else echo $conn->error;
```

Once you've done this successfully, it will not be possible to enter a duplicate `Username` value in this table; The query will not execute and will produce an error.

Now to avoid errors when your script tries to insert a username that already exists, change your insert query from `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO UserDetail SET Username='$escaped_new_username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

By the way your code fails because you're trying to echo the result of `$conn->query`, but it's not a string. The steps to showing DB results are:

1. Run the query (you did)
2. Verify that there was no error by checking that the result is not `false`
3. Fetch results by executing `fetch` `fetch_assoc`, `fetch_array` or some such method on the result
4. Use or show what you fetched.

   Look at the documentation for the DB driver you're using. The most common are [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) and [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)